# How to add 'Set-cookie' header on rest POST response

Tags: cookies, 8

I have subdomain front.test.local as frontend ngx-app and another subdomain back.test.local for the backend pure Drupal both on https - cookie-domain is set to '.test.local'. I need cookie because views resource with image thumbnails in private://.
I trying to get a cookie on frontend after login response in a second request to custom post resource /custom/cookie again basic_auth.
I adding a headers array

```
    $headers = ['Set-cookie'=>'sess_name=sess_id', 'test: name=value;'];
```

to return from post resource

```
    new ModifiedResourceResponse($data, 200, $headers);
```

The response headers seem the same every time: ["content-language", "cache-control", "content-type", "expires"] - no 'test', no cookies

Is it possible to set additional response headers, 'Set-cookie' or another? 
For now, I sending a sessName and sessID in this second response and frontend create a cookie - and this works fine, but it will be nice to set this cookie through a set-cookie header though.

edit2:
improved workaround to skip doubled post with basic_auth (which produce 2 sessions) to one - gist to CustomLoginResource https://gist.github.com/svetlio/156ed32ecccbd38cfae32357a5d6093d return sessId&sessName alongside user id name roles but missing csrf_token , still missing Set-cookie header

Comment: Did you try to call PHP standard [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) before returning your RessoureResponse?

Comment: Yes, I did, no difference in the result.